# Are all scenes in the Phineas and Ferb title sequence part of an episode?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

The title sequence used in the first season of *Phineas and Ferb* contains many fragments of episodes, which I recognise. But I don't recognise all fragments.

**Are all fragments scenes from episodes, or are some only used in the title sequence?**

---

> There's 104 days of summer vacation
>   Then school comes along just to end it
>   So the annual problem for our generation
>   Is finding a good way to spend it
>
> Like maybe:
>   Building a rocket
>   Or fighting a mummy
>   Or climbing up the Eiffel Tower
>
> Discovering something that doesn't exist
>   (Hey!)
>   Or giving a monkey a shower
>
> Surfing tidal waves
>   Creating nanobots
>   Or locating Frankenstein's brain
>   (It's over here!)
>
> Finding a dodo bird
>   Painting a continent
>   Or driving your sister insane
>   (Phineas!)
>
> As you can see
>   There's a whole lot of stuff to do
>   Before school starts this fall
>   (Come on Perry!)
>
> So stick with us 'cause Phineas and Ferb
>   are gonna do it all
>   So stick with us 'cause Phineas and Ferb
>   are gonna do it all!

The song describes much of what we see, but just in case:

1. Phineas and Ferb sitting under a tree.
2. Phineas and Ferb wearing orange space suits, exiting a rocket off-earth, in low gravity.
3. Phineas sitting on Ferb's shoulders, boxing with a mummy (who doesn't seem to be Candace wrapped in rags or toilet paper).
4. Phineas and Ferb climbing up the Eiffel Tower, on the outside, using a rope.
5. Phineas directing Ferb and a bunch of penguins playing trumpets.
6. Ferb pulling a tarp of a creature that is at least part unicorn and part turtle, while Phineas looks on.
7. Phineas and Ferb washing a monkey in a bath tub.
8. Phineas directing Ferb and a bunch of penguins, this time playing guitar.
9. Phineas and Ferb surfing an enormous wave.
10. Phineas and Ferb looking at a swarm of nanobots spelling *HELLO*.
11. Phineas and Ferb finding Frankenstein's (actually Frankenstein's Monster's) brain; Ferb looking into the empty skull of the monster with a torch while Phineas finds the brain in a corner of the room.
12. Phineas and Ferb climbing up a rock or mountain top where a dodo is waiting for them.
13. A helicopter with an enormous paint roller attached flies over a city, painting everything in its wake light orange / dark yellow.
14. Phineas paints a moustache on what looks like a portrait of Candace but actually turns out to be Candace herself.
15. Phineas directs a movie while Ferb operates a puppet octopus.
16. Phineas rides a giant robo-dog while Ferb is standing by with the remote control.
17. Phineas and Ferb are painting and working on a car in the garage, while Candace looks on, angrily.
18. Phineas, Ferb, Isabella and four unidentified kids ride a rollercoaster that is re-entering earth's atmosphere.
19. Candace talks on the phone while Phineas and Ferb transport an elephant outside, behind her.
20. Candace plays *Whack a Pest!*
21. Phineas and Ferb are making a title sequence, while a bunch of stills go by in the background.

---

The fragments from the title sequence don't have to appear *exactly* like that in an episode. They could be different depictions of the same scene. Scenes from the first season's title sequence may appear in episodes of later seasons.

Also, I expect 5, 8, 20, and 21 (the penguin orchestra, *Whack a Pest!*, and the title sequence) not to appear anywhere in episodes.

Lastly, I'm not counting the stills in the final scene. Including them nonetheless, will yield a bonus.

---

> "Mom, Phineas and Ferb are making a title sequence!"

Comment: In multiple episodes (Canderemy, Swiss Family Phineas, Last Train to Bustville) it is implied or outright stated that the P & F gang made the intro first, and are tailoring their adventures to fit....

Answer (score 9):

The video you link to is the season 1 version of the theme song.  It appears that few of the fragments shown are from actual episodes.  The theme song is modified in later seasons to contain more actual quotes though.

Some of the fragments, however, are simliar to real episodes, even if they're not the same.

1. ?
2. The graphics for the spaceship and spacesuits is the same one as in the S3 episode Moon Farm.
3. Phineas and Ferb meet a mummy (actually Candace accidentally dressed as a mummy) in the S1 episode "Are you my mummy?", but the mummy scene the theme song shows apparently isn't from that episode.
4. ?
5. ?
6. In "Fireside Girl Jamboree", Candace finds a turtle unicorn very similar to the one in the title sequence, in a pot at the end of a rainbow, earning a Fireside Girl patch for discovering something that doesn't exist.
7. A monkey in the bathtub can be seen in the S2 episode "Swiss Family Phineas", but they're in a different location and Phineas isn't there.
8. ?
9. ?
10. The nanobots forming letters in the air, controlled with a remote control, is an actual scene in the S3 episode "Norm Unleashed".
11. ?
12. ?
13. The giant paint roller shown when the song sings "painting a continent" is similar to the one shown in the S1 episode "Oil on Candace", but we don't see that paint roller applying yellow paint in that episode.
14. What looks like a framed painting on the wall turns out to be a living person in "Fireside Girl Jamboree", but nobody is painting on it and it's not Candace.
15. ?
16. [The robotic dog](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Rover) appears in some episodes, in season 3 first, but I don't think P&F ever ride it.
17. When the song sings "there's a whole lot of stuff", you can see Phineas and Ferb paint a race car.  Phineas and Ferb beef up a car in about four episodes:

    - The S1 episode "It's a Mud, Mud, Mud, Mud World" where they make a monster truck to teach Candace driving so she can get her driving license
    - In the S1 episode "The fast and the Phineas" where they build a remote-controlled race car
    - In the beginning of the S1 episode "Phineas and Ferb Get Busted!" they build a flying car.

    I believe the scene in the title song isn't from any of those though.
18. Immediately after that, you see a roller-coaster starting to burn as it re-enters the atmosphere.  That scene is very similar to the very first episode of the show, "Rollercoaster", but even this fragment isn't an actual quote from the episode.  In the episode, a boy with black hair is sitting next to Isabella, whereas in the song it's a boy with brown hair.  The coaster is longer in the episode as well.
19. ?
20. ?
21. ?

[The fandom page for the title song](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb_Theme) and [the one for the extended version](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Today_is_Gonna_Be_a_Great_Day) gives some further hints about this, but it's mostly concerned with the feats mentioned in the lyrics, rather that what we see on screen.

Comment: O yeah, the monkey I the bath tub. I think they say they _had_ to do that.

Comment: Last Train to Bustville - they don't climb a mountain but they see a dodo and cross it off their 'intro list'

Answer (score 1):

The paint roller appears in the original movie while they showed most inventions and it was the same color as the one in the title sequence.

Maybe they paint a continent off screen somehow, or it’s just the one from “Oil on Candace”.

Answer (score 0):

The monkey one it was the episode where Phineas and Ferb crash on a deserted island and they build a giant shelter and inside they are giving a monkey a shower. It was the same episode Doofenshmirtz makes a Laundryinator inside a volcano.

Comment: You've provided one example, but what about all the other examples that come up in the theme tune?

Comment: This could use some fleshing out and more examples.